# Refresh Multiple DataTables using new API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

After taking time to read the new DataTable 1.10.2 API, I think I am getting better now. So far I have reduced my over 200 line code to just less than 100 and doing the same thing much better. Now I am stuck with the datatables not refreshing when a data changes. The code below refreshes only the .getJSON function but the datas not refreshed on the 2 tables in browser:

```
        $(document).ready(function (){
            var alertTable = $('#alert-table').DataTable({
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "host" },
                    { "data": "description" },
                    { "data": "value", "visible": false }
                ],
            });

            var errorTable = $('#error-table').DataTable({
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "host" },
                    { "data": "description" }
                ],

            });


            setInterval (function(){
                $.getJSON("data/json_data.txt", function (pcheckdata){

                    alertTable.clear();
                    alertTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.alerts).draw();
                    alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();

                    errorTable.clear();
                    errorTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.errors).draw();
                    errorTable.columns.adjust().draw();
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
```

This is what I see when i inspect firefox console:

```
GET data/json_data.txt 200 OK 10ms
```

Comment: your could tryout `oTable.fnDraw();` after doing all your operations.

Comment: Thanks @D.T. i had identified the error.

Comment: nice one, easy updatable datatables :)

Answer (score 1):

silly me, I just noticed my mistake, forgot to add .draw() after .clear()

```
                alertTable.clear().draw();
                alertTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.alerts).draw();
                alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();

                errorTable.clear().draw();
                errorTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.errors).draw();
                errorTable.columns.adjust().draw();
```